# iOS Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a UIImageView. And when click on it, a `UIActionSheet` will pop up.

```
@IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func tapUIImageViewHandler(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var popMenu: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Upload user avatar", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Choose from library", "Take photo")
    popMenu.showInView(self.view)
}

func actionSheet(popMenu: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
    println("click at index \(buttonIndex)")
    switch buttonIndex {
    case 2:
        takePhoto()
    case 1:
        chooseFromLib()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

But when I run it on simulator, after I click the button on the UIActionSheet, I get

> Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation
>   or dismiss is in progress!

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: are you taking image from library?

Comment: The warning implies that you have an animation that hasn't completely finished prior to firing another animation transition.

Comment: @MohitPopat even I click on "Cancel", this warning will appear.

Comment: @Thought-Beast But I'm not doing any animation here?

Comment: before presenting action sheet are you presenting any other view or controller?

Comment: @randomp ActionSheet presenting/dismissing happens with an animation. Are you triggering any other animation while actionSheet animation of present/dismiss is already running ?

Comment: @MohitPopat yes. The imageView and the whole UIViewController.

Comment: @Thought-Beast I don't thinker I trigger other animation.

Comment: before presenting actionsheet dismiss imageview

Comment: if it does not work then use navigation controller to present view controller

Comment: I always get the same warning when using a UIActionSheet

Comment: best solution for this do not present the Actionsheet but use this [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; change it acccording to swift syntax

Comment: @MohitPopat yah, I'm using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it is a bug (you should file a bug report. I tested a simpler project (with only a button and an action opening the ActionSheet, no delegate) in the following cases:

- Swift XCode Beta 4 -> warning
- ObjC XCode Beta 4 -> warning
- ObjC Xcode 5.1.1 -> OK

By the way I remember you that since iOS8 ActionSheet is replaced by `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyle` set to `ActionSheet`. But it is also true that we must continue to use ActionSheet, especially because we all probably still target version < 8.

Comment: I'm using XCode 6, beta 4 and Swift

Comment: I use UIAlertController to replace UIActionSheet and there is no warning.

Answer (score 1):

Please implement small delay while presenting actionsheet.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentActionsheet) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2f];
```